# Get textValue() from JSON in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin

I'm trying to get the textValue() of "reason" from the json input shown below

```
{
  "data": {
    "errors": {
      "array": [
        {
          "field": "recipientId",
          "reason": "Not Registered"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

so far I was able to get it with this

```
val jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(input) 


val reason = jsonNode.get("data")?.get("errors")?.get("array")?.map { it }?.get(0)?.get("reason")?.textValue().orEmpty()
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to get the value

Comment: There is a better way using Gson: Gson().fromJson<YourDataClass>(yourJsonString, YourDataClass::class.java)

Comment: This mostly looks like the standard way to access values from Jacksons node tree, except what is the `map` for? You may want to explain why you think this way is a problem. Have a look at [`path`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#path(java.lang.String)) instead of `get` and the safe calls. And `asText()` instead of `textValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write the JSON string back to Kotlin data class.

```
data class Root(
   val data: Data,
)

data class Data(
    val errors: Errors,
)

data class Errors(
    val array: List<Array>,
)

data class Array(
    val field: String,
    val reason: String,
)
```

An example with FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin:

```
val objectMapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()

objectMapper.registerModule()

val root: Root = objectMapper.readValue(json)
```

And you can easily generate your data class:

https://transform.tools/json-to-kotlin